# Как узнать свойства родителя в классе, созданном внутри родителя?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, классы

Подскажите, как узнать свойства родителя в классе, созданном внутри родителя? Пример:

```
class Animal {
   public $name;

   function set($newname) {
      $this->name = $newname;
      $dog = new Dog();
      $dog->say();
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   function say() {
      echo $this->name;
   }
}

$a = new Animal();
$a->set('Somename');
```

Comment: Приведенный код приведет к бесконечной рекурсии, если вообще выполнится. `var` в PHP не используют с какого-то бородатого года. А так все правильно, просто $this->name.

Comment: @Etki, изменил на public $name + избавился от рекурсии, но все равно у родителя свойство не знает.

Comment: ошибка в коде :)

Comment: Чушь какая-то... Зачем в сеттере имени создавать экземпляр класса? Пускай это даже и синтетический пример, но всё же крайне нелогичный.

Comment: @rimlin, вы в методе set создаете новый объект. Теперь такой вопрос: тот объект, который создался, и тот, который $this, - являются ли они одни и тем же объектом, чтобы можно было говорить о родительской связи?

Answer (score 1):

> но все равно у родителя свойство не знает.

Дочерний класс, наследует все свойства и методы, присущие родителю.
Проверить это можно следующим образом:

```
$a = new Dog();
$a->set('Somename');
$a->say();
```